# How to input a dynamically changing parameter in NDSolve?

Tags: function-construction

I am trying to solve a system of DEs with additional conditions, and one condition depends on a parameter. Let us consider the following example:

```
eq = D[y,x]==2;
cond = y[1]==param;
NDSolve[{eq,cond},y[x],x]
```

How do I make a function that takes the input of a number `param` and outputs the `NDSolve` result with the corresponding parameter? I tried to make the condition itself a function, but this doesn't work:

```
eq = D[y,x]==2;
cond[param_] := y[1]==param
fun[param1_] := NDSolve[{eq,cond[param1]},y[x],x]
```

PS. There is a [somewhat similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/47141/edit), but there the parameter is of Boolean nature.

Comment: Search for parameter + ndsolve in the docs, or try `psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, cond}, y, {x, 1, 10}, {param}]`.  (Note `eq` should be `D[y[x],x] == 2`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, `ParametricNDSolve` seems to be exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome.  In that case, I think will vote to put on hold as the answer being found in the documentation, which is the standard thing to do here. +1 for a clear question, anyway :)